# Laravel - unable to migrate DB

Tags: laravel, migration

Im learning laravel, and now im unable to migrate the database. I have already created the db in phpmyadmin, have read the documentation and made a research on the net about the issue. However, when i make migrate, it keeps sending the same message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `YYYY`.`#sql-269c_1c1` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table ` cars` add constraint `cars_company_id_foreign` foreign key (`Company_id`) references `companies` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)
```

This is the code:

2014_10_12_000000_create_cars_table

```
Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('Company_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('Company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('Model');
    });
```

2014_10_12_000000_create_companies_table

```
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('Company');
    });
```

Comment: what DB engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel tries to run your migrations in order of 1) time, 2) alphabet. Since you gave both of your migrations the same time, it's going by alphabetical order instead.

What this means in practice is that you're trying to create the cars table first, with a foreign key constraint pointing to a table companies - but this table does not yet exist, since it's going to be created in the next migration.

Name your migrations properly and it should resolve itself. :)

Comment: I have altered the date in the files name to get them to migrate in order. And it works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Yea as Joel Said  be careful on migration naming convention.
To avoid these errors you can use migration commands

**step1**
Run below from command line

```
php artisan make:migration create_companies_table
```

**step2**

This will make blank migration schema in your database and then edit it like below

```
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('Company');
    });
```

**step 3** 
Run below from command line

```
php artisan make:migration create_companies_table
```

**step 4**
This will make blank migration schema in your database and then edit it like below

```
Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('Company_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('Company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('Model');
    });
```

Comment: Didnt knew that its possible to make migrate files. It now works. Thanks!

Comment: How do i do that? i didnt knew that we can mark answers as correct.